# Получение данных о беседе по peer_id. Vk_api. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Нужно получить название беседы по её peer_id, но при попытке сделать по большинству готовых примеров - бросает ошибку.

```py
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='15b2db6c*******************************************e97c4e7')

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, **********)
vk = vk_session.get_api()

pid = 2000000003

# сточка с ошибкой
title1 = vk.method("messages.getChatPreview", {"peer_id": pid})["title"]

# цель: получить название беседы
```

Comment: Подскажите, какая ошибка у Вас появляется при попытке получить данные? Пробовали получать не через `getChatPreview`, а через `getChat`? `title = vk_api.method("messages.getChat", {"peer_id": pid})["title"]`

Comment: Exception has occurred: TypeError
__call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given Выдаёт эту ошибку в вашем случае включительно

Comment: Если у вас нет прав администратора в конфе - названия вы не получите. О чём сказано в документации. Не уверен даже, что с правами админа у вас будет к этому доступ.

Comment: Существуют же боты по типу "Кай" и обычно "Чат мэнеджера", в них же собирается информация о названии, участниках? Мне примерно это и нужно